# Open an image with the Windows default editor in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, image

In my C# application, I would like to launch the default image editor to edit an image.

When I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\image.png")` it opens the image file using the [Windows Photo Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/view-and-use-your-pictures-in-windows-photo-viewer).

When I right-click on the image file in Windows Explorer, there is a "Edit" menu item which launches Microsoft Paint (by default). I would like to do the same in my application (i.e. open the file using the default image editor).

I don't want to hardcode MS Paint by doing `Process.Start("mspaint.exe C:\\image.png")`. I would prefer to use the default image editor program set by the user (which can be different from MS Paint).

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks
Frank

Comment: I have Small Error in datagridview see the below link   

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283410/executablepath-use-to-show-image-in-datagridview-c-sharp-windows-form-applicatio

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try starting a process with a verb `edit`.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\image.png");
startInfo.Verb="edit";

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: Specifying ProcessStartInfo.Verb does not appear to be necessary if all you want to do is display the image using the program associated with the file extension.

Comment: No, but it is if you want to edit it, which was pretty much the essence of the question.

Comment: This works for any file not just images, however, I had to resort to a `try { } catch (Win32Exception) { }` to handle files where no default edit action is defined.

Comment: when used in windows 8.1 it opens in photviewer and throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want open your image in the pictureBox by a Default Winndows Editor try this;

```
//Create temporary file name
String TMP_IMAGE = "tempImage" +DateTime.Now.Millisecond +".bmp";

//get the folder of application
string PATH_APP =                
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + @"\tempImage\";

//Create a subFolder tempImage
Directory.CreateDirectory(PATH_APP);

//Save a new path in a variable
String NEW_PATH = PATH_APP + TMP_IMAGE;

//Save the image in the pictureBox in the new path and file name
pictureBox.Image.Save(NEW_PATH);

//Lunch the process with defaoul image editor in the comouter
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(NEW_PATH);
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: what is `pictureBox`  here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=netframework-4.8     @BabarBaig