# How to open images on default image viewer in WPF

Tags: wpf, image

I am binding my images which are coming from server in the listview .These images are bitmap images. When I click on any of the image from the listview I want it to open in the default Image-Viewer on Windows. Any way to achieve this ?

Comment: `Process.Start(imagepath)` should do it.

Comment: That is your answer ... Repost it and accept it :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an image with the Windows default editor in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022188/open-an-image-with-the-windows-default-editor-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808029/open-image-in-windows-photo-viewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a default viewer, there should be an association for the extension of the file. As a result, you can just shell-start the file. Use `Process.Start` like,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("imagePath");
```